# How do I get how many time one item is repeated from a list in python?

Tags: python

For example, i have a list
the outputs should look like

3

4

```
bob= [ 1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(random_method(bob, 2))
print(random_method(bob, 3))
```

Comment: can explain bit more about your random_method()

Comment: Do you want to pick a random item from the list? What does `2` mean in `random_method(bob, 2)`

Comment: Are you looking to get the ith UNIQUE item from the list?

Comment: 2 is the number that you are looking for how many times it is been repeated in the list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bob= [ 1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,3,4,5,6]
def random_method(b,i):
  return b.count(i)
print(random_method(bob, 2))
print(random_method(bob, 3))
```